# swim workouts from swim-a-mile website

Tags: swimming

I've just completed the 0 to 1 mile swim program (http://ruthkazez.com/swimming/ZeroTo1mile.html). Now I am planning to follow the workouts in http://ruthkazez.com/swimming/IntroToSwimWorkouts.html
for a couple of months.

However, I am not quite sure how to interpret the last item of the various workouts. For example, for workout 1, it says
Backstroke  5x50 swim, kick, drill, swim. Big hip roll.
Does this mean 50m of swimming backstroke, 50m of backstroke kick, 50m of a backstroke drill of my choice and 50m of backstroke swim again? thats only 4x50. is the last 50 of "big hip roll"?

For workout 2. its
Breaststroke 400 drills, swim, pull, kick
Is that 100m of each, i.e. one drill, then 100 swim 100 pull 100 kick?

Perhaps there is a general logic to the last part of these workouts that I fail to see.

Comment: How much time did it take you?

Answer (score 1):

I think the 5x50 is either a typo, or has a missing element. It should be (as you guess) 5x50, 1 50 of swim, 1 50 of kick, 1 50 of drill and 1 50 of swim. The "Big hip roll" is to make sure that you emphasize the hip roll when you are doing all of this. I would suspect that the missing 50 is probably a 50 of pull (Arms only).

And yes, on the second workout, it is 100 each of the segment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since the workout names five types of drills right after saying 5x50, I'd interpret that as one 50 of each. The interpretation of the second set is also right, especially if you take time to use equipment in the pull and kick. But you could of course divide that 400 as four 100s, eight 50s or even sixteen 25s. If your coach is not on deck, you decide, I'd say.

Good luck on getting more fit in swimming, and don't be hesitant to contact the local club (you've probably seen them at the pool) to see if they can help you or if they have a masters group you can join so that you get some company working out, wich makes it so much easier.